# ¿Cómo realizar un split en SQL server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2008-r2

Buenas, quería saber si es posible llevar a cabo un split como se muestra abajo, dado que necesito recibir una cadena de palabras separadas por coma; hasta el momento no me han servido los métodos que he visto en internet.

```
SELECT *
FROM BASE
WHERE Doc in (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DocV,','))
```

Comment: En este [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20513630/3200493) puedes encontrar una función que ya realiza el `split` y tiene como separador comas y viene un ejemplo de cómo usarla.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que necesito utilizar dicho método desde un procedimiento almacenado

Comment: @Christian: Las respuestas abajo te permiten crear una función de split que luego puedes ejecutar desde tu procedimiento almacenado. No veo que haya un problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías hacer esto, que separa automáticamente por el caracter `,`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
@returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

y lo usás:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('91,12,65,78,56,789')
```

Comment: Que pena, una vez la creo me queda almacenada en las bases de datos en una carpeta propia, como puedo llamar dicha función desde un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Deberías llamarla así dentro de su SP `SELECT *
FROM BASE
WHERE Doc in (SELECT * NombreBaseDeDatos.Usurario.splitstring(@DocV))`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar esta función.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Split]
(
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5)
)
RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE (Indice INT, Data NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Counter INT
        SET @Counter = 1
        WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) > 0 )
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @ReturnValue (Indice, data )
                SELECT  Indice = @Counter, Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) - 1)))
            SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) + 1, LEN(@RowData))
            SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
        END
        INSERT INTO @ReturnValue ( Indice, data )
        SELECT Indice = @Counter , Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

        RETURN
    END;
```