# Problema con nombres y apellidos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

El problema es en buscar datos que están escritos de otra manera. Me explico:

En SQL Server tengo una base de datos donde tengo una columna llamada `ALUMNO` y los nombres están escritos de esta manera:

> **MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ HECTOR**

Ahora, en una página web que busca los datos por el nombre y después apellidos, los busca así:

> **HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ**

¿Hay manera de que en SQL Server busque los datos sin importar como estén escritos por decir que se parezcan?

Tengo esto:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TUTORIAS WHERE ALUMNO='HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ'
```

Pero no me da nada ya que en la base de datos están primero escrito los apellidos y después el nombre.

No quiero cambiar la página web por que es mucho y tendría que volverla a hacer y es mas fácil arreglar esto.

Comment: No tienes discriminados en dos columnas el apellido y nombre?

Comment: No en una sola columna tengo el nombre completo pero empieza por apellidos y luego los nombres(si tiene mas de 1)

Comment: Si puedes hacer el cambio, deberías dividir esos campos para que sea más facil y rápida la búsqueda.

Comment: no puedo dividirlos ese el problema

Comment: Hola Victor, agregue la etiqueta "mysql", es importante especificat ya que de otra forma vas a recibir respuestas que tal vez no sean adecuadas.

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje de programación usas en el lado del servidor?

Comment: La solución más sencilla es crear un [crear un índice de texto completo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (similar a la solución de [Guillermo Marighetti](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/160090/guillermo-marighetti)). Luego puedes hacer consultas usando [`FREETEXT ()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15#example---freetext).

Comment: **Lo correcto** es tener nombre y apellidos en diferentes columnas de bbdd. Cualquier solución que no use este sistema tendrá alguna penalización de rendimiento

Comment: @Julio, es lo correcto y eso lo entiende el autor de la pregunta. Parece que es una aplicación que ha heredado y parece que no puede modificar el esquema sin alterar su funcionamiento: **"No quiero cambiar la página web por que es mucho y tendría que volverla a hacer y es mas fácil arreglar esto"**. Aunque quizá podría crear una vista con el mismo nombre que la tabla y campos por compatibilidad y que los datos reales estén almacenados en otra tabla de manera correcta. Pero requiere de un proceso de migración que hay que planificar bien (sobre todo si hay claves externas, iniciadores, etc).

Answer (score 2):

La solución más sencilla es crear un crear un [índice de texto completo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). La respuesta de [@Guillermo Marighetti](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/160090/guillermo-marighetti) es similar a ésta, pero relacionada con MySQL, no con SQL Server.

Lo primero que deberías hacer para crear un índice de texto completo es crear un catálogo por defecto:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG nombres AS DEFAULT
```

Una vez que tu base de datos tiene un catálogo podremos insertar datos en él relacionando los términos con los registros a través de una clave (única o primaria).

Como no sé cómo se llaman las claves de tu tabla, voy a presuponer el siguiente esquema para continuar la explicación:

```
CREATE TABLE TUTORIAS (
  ID INT,
  ALUMNO VARCHAR(250),
  CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

En este caso la clave primaria se llama `PK_ID` y está formada únicamente por el campo `ID`. Es importante entender la diferencia entre el nombre de los campos que componen una clave y el nombre de la clave.

Ahora utilizamos [`ADD FULLTEXT INDEX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) para agregar los términos del campo `ALUMNO` (y todos los campos que deseemos) al catálogo:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON TUTORIAS (
  ALUMNO
) KEY INDEX PK_ID;
```

Con esta instrucción se relacionarán los términos del campo `ALUMNO` con la clave primaria (`PK_ID`) de los registros que contienen dichos términos.

A partir de ahora se puede hacer una búsqueda te texto completo haciendo uso de, por ejemplo, [`FREETEXT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15#example---freetext) de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT ALUMNO FROM TUTORIAS
WHERE FREETEXT (ALUMNO, 'HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ')
```

---

También puedes definir un catálogo nuevo, que no sea el catálogo por defecto, indicando posteriormente de manera explícita en qué catálogo vamos a guardar los términos:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON TUTORIAS (
  ALUMNO
) KEY INDEX PK_ID
ON nombres;
```

---

Nota: El agente de SQL Server es el que proporciona la capacidad de búsqueda de texto completo. Si no te funciona la búsqueda o la creación del índice de texto completo comprueba que éste arranca junto con el sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede funcionar,

> 1. Inicia añadiendo un indice FULLTEXT a tu tabla y al campo deseado.

```
ALTER TABLE tutorias ADD FULLTEXT(ALUMNO);
```

> 2. Ejecuta tu consulta con las siguientes modificaciones.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TUTORIAS WHERE MATCH (ALUMNO) AGAINST ('HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ')
```

> 3. Te retornaria el siguiente resultado.

[image: Retorno de la consulta.]

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar uso sql server management 17 lo intente poner pero no me deja

Comment: Te hago referencia a dos paginas de la documentacion de Microsoft sobre SQL Server para que puedas adaptar el codigo a SQL, cabe aclarar que la etiqueta de la pregunta señala mysql.

https://bit.ly/388Nci5

https://bit.ly/3cg9MbQ

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el operador Like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TUTORIAS WHERE ALUMNO LIKE 'HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ%'
```

Te dejo la doc para que leas bien como usar ese operador.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ya probe de varias maneras y sigue sin funcionar con el like, ya habia intentado usar el like pero sigo con el mismo problema

Comment: Tenes que usarlo parcial no completo. Si coloca nombre completo usas el =

Comment: Pro decir de esta manera: SELECT * FROM dbo.TUTORIAS WHERE ALUMNO =  'HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ%' si es asi no funciono

Comment: Considera que el OP no usa SQL Server sino MySQL, por lo tanto convendría verifiques esta sintaxis `dbo.TUTORIAS`

Comment: Uso sql no si se sea un problema?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar el comodin LIKE de esta manera:

Ejemplo:

```
                SELECT * FROM  Person WHERE dni LIKE '%415%';
```

Comment: No me esta funcionando con el like

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo mejor como dicen es dividirlo en nombre y apellido, pero si es mucho trabajo puedes usar esto no es lo mas eficiente que puedes hacer pero funciona

```
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE Alumno LIKE '%HECTOR%' AND Alumno LIKE '%MARTINEZ%' AND Alumno LIKE '%HERNANDEZ%'
```

---

```
create table #temp(
    Alumno VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP(ALUMNO) VALUES('MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ HECTOR')
INSERT INTO #TEMP(ALUMNO) VALUES('MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ JORGE')
INSERT INTO #TEMP(ALUMNO) VALUES('MORALES HERNANDEZ HECTOR')

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE Alumno LIKE '%HECTOR%' AND Alumno LIKE '%MARTINEZ%' AND Alumno LIKE '%HERNANDEZ%'
```

Y el resultado es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualizacion:
Con esto evitas lo que me comentas**

```
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE Alumno LIKE '%HECTOR%' AND Alumno LIKE '%MARTINEZ%' AND Alumno LIKE '%HERNANDEZ%' AND LEN(Alumno) = len('MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ HECTOR')
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar ya lo intente asi pero me manda todos los nombres que se parecen y no  uno en especifico :c

Comment: Si? si lo pusiste igual mira te paso todo el ejercicio o como que nombres te regresa

Comment: Ya te entendi si tiene otro nombre verdad si tu buscas MORALES HERNANDEZ HECTOR pero existe alguien llamado MORALES HERNANDEZ JUAN HECTOR te regresa los 2s

Comment: @VictorA Actualice el codigo

Comment: Si usas MySql cambia len por LENGTH

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comenta nuestro compañero es lo correcto, deberias de tener dos campos completamente diferente uno para nombre y otros para apellidos.

Comentas que no puedes hacerlo... Yo intentaría transformar la base de datos para tenerlo separado no obstante te dejo una solución aunque creo que no será la mas optima:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre)),CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre))),50)+' '+SUBSTRING(Nombre,0,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre)))) FROM dbo.TUTORIAS
```

Te explico para poder sacar solo el nombre en este caso utilizaríamos lo siguiente:

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre)),CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre))),50)
```

El SUBSTRING lo que le indicas es como cortar el string el primer valor es el string, el segundo desde donde empieza y el tercero donde acaba.

Con el CHARINDEX seleccionamos un carácter y el string y nos devuelve la posición de ese carácter.

Básicamente lo que hago aquí es recorrer el string primero quito hasta el primer espacio que seria esto:

```
SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre)
```

Hasta este punto tenemos quitado el primer apellido, al resultado tenemos que quitarle el segundo:

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre)),CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre))),50)
```

Y por Ultimo selecionar los dos apellidos:

```
SUBSTRING(Nombre,0,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(Nombre,CHARINDEX(' ',Nombre)+1,LEN(Nombre))))
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda pero no obstante deberías de plantearte el separar en campos nombre y apellido

Esto puedes transformarlo en una vista para tener la opción de buscarlo de ambas maneras.

Answer (score 0):

Si trabajas en php lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
$nombrequellegadelaweb = 'HECTOR MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ';
$nombre = explode(' ', $nombrequellegadelaweb);
$nombrequebuscas = $nombre[1].' '.$nombre[2].' '.$nombre[0];
$consultasql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TUTORIAS WHERE ALUMNO = $nombrequebuscas";
```

Lo que hace explode de php es hacer que una cadena de texto se convierta en un array separandola por el caracter que le indicas, por lo que le pones `' '`, de esta manera separa por los espacios, entonces tu array `$nombre` en el ejemplo quedaría tal que así

```
$nombre[0] = 'HECTOR';
$nombre[1] = 'MARTINEZ';
$nombre[2] = 'HERNANDEZ';
```

Con lo que concatenando los campos en el orden que necesitas, te buscará el nombre que deseas en el formato que necesitas.

También para asegurarte puedes concatenarlos y ponerlos en mayúsculas por si acaso no te llega igual que como lo tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando como base la función de Pablo Claus [splitstring](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35716/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-un-split-en-sql-server-2008-r2)

puedes crear una segunda función como la siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstringReverse(@stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @returnList TABLE ([ID] Int Identity(1,1),[Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @indicador int = 0

    WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), @stringToSplit) > 0
        BEGIN
            IF @indicador = 1
                SET @stringToSplit = REVERSE(@stringToSplit)

            SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), @stringToSplit)  
            SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

            IF @indicador = 0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @returnList([Name])
                    SELECT REVERSE(@name)
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @returnList([Name])
                    SELECT @name
                END

            SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)

            SET @indicador = @indicador + 1

        END

        INSERT INTO @returnList([Name])
        SELECT @stringToSplit

    RETURN
END
GO

BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #Temp1 FROM dbo.splitstring('HECTOR HUGO MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ')
    SELECT * INTO #Temp2 FROM dbo.splitstringReverse(Reverse('MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ HECTOR HUGO'))

    SELECT * FROM #Temp1
    SELECT * FROM #Temp2

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp1 A LEFT JOIN #Temp2 B ON A.Name = B.Name AND CASE WHEN A.ID = 1 THEN 99 ELSE A.ID END >= B.ID WHERE B.Name IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'IGUALES'
        END

    DROP TABLE #Temp1
    DROP TABLE #Temp2
END
GO
```