# Separar una columna es varias filas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia.

Quiero dividir una columna que tiene varios datos divididos con coma (,).

La columna original es asi

[image: columna Original]

y quiero que se muestre en filas, como se muestra acontinuacion.

[image: Resultado esperado]

La version de mi sql es:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU7-GDR) (KB4505222) - 13.0.5366.0 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 08:22:25   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: ¿Te refieres a una consulta o a modificar la estructura? El problema que estas teniendo se debe a un mal diseño de la base de datos que no cumple la 1FN por tener valores no atómicos. En mi experiencia si lo dejas así, los problemas irán creciendo y las consultas serán cada vez mas complejas.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no me sirve el split. my sql no reconoce el comando.

Comment: @derloopkat sera en una consulta, la base de datos ya fue diseña asi.

Comment: si tu versión de SQL Server es 2016, deberías poder usar STRING_SPLIT. En qué modo de compatibilidad está tu base de datos?

Comment: Esta función te podría ayudar [¿Cómo realizar un split en SQL server 2008 r2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35716/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-un-split-en-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: @Lamak la compatibilidad esta en nivel 130

Comment: @Giovanni extraño, eso es SQL Server 2016. Puedes poner el msje de error que te da si usas esa función?

Comment: encontre un enlace que me funciono, es el siguiente: https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/sql/consulta-sql-para-dividir-datos-de-columna-en-filas/1070274813/